# Accessing Individual Images in Multipage TIFF in Mathematica

Tags: import, wolfram-mathematica, tiff, multipage

I have 12 large (1gb each) multi-page TIFF files containing 1500 images that represent a time series of 3D data.
To keep memory consumption at bay, i would like to only read individual images from the multi-page TIFF files, instead of reading everything and then selecting only the required file.
Is there an option to Import that I'm missing or is there another approach?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try for example:

```
pageNbr = 3;
Import["C:\\test1.tif", {"ImageList", pageNbr}]
```